# crash error when execute docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I executed the command

```
docker-compose down
```

and get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 115, in perform_command
File "compose/cli/command.py", line 37, in project_from_options
File "compose/cli/command.py", line 91, in get_project
File "compose/config/config.py", line 362, in load
File "compose/config/config.py", line 528, in process_config_file
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 378, in 
validate_against_config_schema
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 439, in handle_errors
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 439, in <genexpr>
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 365, in 
process_config_schema_errors
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 237, in handle_generic_error
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 305, in 
_parse_oneof_validator
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 320, in 
_parse_oneof_validator
File "compose/config/validation.py", line 285, in 
_parse_valid_types_from_validator
 File "compose/config/validation.py", line 201, in anglicize_json_type
e
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I don't know what happened, everything was ok yesterday then just goes wrong today without any reasons.

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9
```

Comment: Would https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22993#issuecomment-290704511 or https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4385#issuecomment-275061492 help?

Comment: i don't install docker and docker-compose by pip, i used apt (ubuntu)

Comment: OK Is there anything in docker logs (or docker daemon logs)?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your docker-compose.yml (or equivalent)?

Comment: thank you all, but i solved the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, solved the problem. but unfortunately, I don't know exactly what i did.
I executed this command:

```
pip freeze | grep docker
```

and saw that i have docker, docker-compose, docker-py packages in Python, but i still have docker, docker-compose in the system (Ubuntu). Perhaps they caused some conflicts somewhere.
So I uninstall all docker, docker-related-packages in python.

After that, I stop all containers running in docker (not using docker-compose down anymore, I used some command found on the internet), remove almost containers' config, and run docker-compose up again. It works.

So I add perspective containers' config, when adding Nginx container's config to docker-compose.yml, the problem appeared again. So I changed in  nginx's config and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed Docker Toolbox on my Windows 10 machine.

My Solution:

1) Install Docker Community Edition (not Docker Toolbox)

Download site= https://www.docker.com/community-edition

2) Enable Hyper-V

Open Control Panel -> System and Security -> Programs (left panel) -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Check the Hyper-V box

3) Add C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin to Path in Environmental Variables.

4) Open Git Bash and type "docker-compose up" and now that command should work. 
If you don't have GitBash, please download it.